# PYODBC ERROR: SQL data argument out of range (30030) (SQL Bind Parameter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, db2

I am trying to insert data with Python to a DB2 database, here is the code that I have:

```
window=Tk()
window.title('Seguimiento')
window.geometry("1200x628")
titulo = Label(text="Base de Datos de Seguimiento", font=("Arial", 16, 'bold'), fg="White", bg="Blue")
titulo.pack()

conn_db2 = pyodbc.connect('DSN=AS400; UID=%s; PWD=%s' % ( uname, password ) )

centro_cursor = conn_db2.cursor()
resultado_centro = []
buscar_centro = "SELECT centro FROM BIUMO220.TICKCENTRO"
centro_cursor.execute(buscar_centro)
for loop_centro in centro_cursor:
     resultado_centro.append(loop_centro[0])

intervencion_cursor = conn_db2.cursor()
resultado_intervencion = []
buscar_intervencion = "SELECT tipo_intervencion FROM BIUMO220.TICKINTERVENCION"
intervencion_cursor.execute(buscar_intervencion)
for loop_intervencion in intervencion_cursor:
     resultado_intervencion.append(loop_intervencion[0])

resultado_intervencion = list(dict.fromkeys(resultado_intervencion))

responsable = StringVar()
fecha = IntVar()
centro = StringVar()
tipo_intervencion = StringVar()
subtipo_intervencion = StringVar()
comentario = StringVar()
ref_producto_final = StringVar()
descripcion_producto_final = StringVar()
ref_componente = StringVar()
util = StringVar()
tiempo_aprox_intervencion = StringVar()

responsable_ = "Responsable: " + uname
hoy = date.today()
global insertar_fecha
insertar_fecha = hoy.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
fecha_hoy = hoy.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
fecha_ = "Fecha: " + fecha_hoy

def seleccionar_subtipo(e):
    subtipo_intervencion_cursor = conn_db2.cursor()
    global resultado_subtipo_intervencion
    resultado_subtipo_intervencion = []
    seleccion_intervencion = tipo_intervencion_desplegable.get()
    buscar_subtipo = "SELECT subtipo FROM BIUMO220.TICKINTERVENCION WHERE 
    tipo_intervencion = ?"
    subtipo_intervencion_cursor.execute(buscar_subtipo, seleccion_intervencion)
    for loop_subtipo_intervencion in subtipo_intervencion_cursor:
        resultado_subtipo_intervencion.append(loop_subtipo_intervencion[0])
        subtipo_intervencion_desplegable.config(value=(resultado_subtipo_intervencion))

def producto_final_descripcion_familia(i):
    global res
    global ref
    cur = conn_db2.cursor()
    ref = referencia_producto_final_entrada.get()
    res = []
    sql = "SELECT E.TEBEZ1, E.TEBEZ2, A.TXTXB1 FROM BIDBD220.TEIL E, BIDBD220.TABDS A WHERE E.TETENR = ? AND A.TXTXRT = 'TL' AND E.TEPRKL = LTRIM(A.TXTXNR)  AND A.TXSPCD = 'S'"
    cur.execute(sql, ref)
    row = cur.fetchall()
    for rows in row:
        res.append(rows)
        descripcion_producto_final_entrada1.config(text=res)

def componente_descripcion_familia(j):
    global referencia_componente
    global componente_resultado
    componente_cursor = conn_db2.cursor()
    componente_resultado = []
    referencia_componente = referencia_componente_entrada.get()
    componente_query = "SELECT E.TEBEZ1, E.TEBEZ2, A.TXTXB1 FROM BIDBD220.TEIL E, BIDBD220.TABDS A WHERE E.TETENR = ? AND A.TXTXRT = 'TL' AND E.TEPRKL = LTRIM(A.TXTXNR)  AND A.TXSPCD = 'S'"
    componente_cursor.execute(componente_query, referencia_componente)
    componente_row = componente_cursor.fetchall()
    for com in componente_row:
        componente_resultado.append(com)
        descripcion_componente_entrada.config(text=componente_resultado)

def util_descripcion_familia(k):
    global referencia_util
    global util_resultado
    util_cursor = conn_db2.cursor()
    referencia_util = util_entrada.get()
    util_resultado = []
    util_query = "SELECT TRIM(E.TEBEZ1), TRIM(E.TEBEZ2), TRIM(A.TXTXB1) FROM BIDBD220.TEIL E, BIDBD220.TABDS A WHERE E.TETENR = ? AND A.TXTXRT = 'TL' AND E.TEPRKL = LTRIM(A.TXTXNR)  AND A.TXSPCD = 'S'"
    util_cursor.execute(util_query, referencia_util)
    util_row = util_cursor.fetchall()
    for uti in util_row:
        util_resultado.append(uti)
        descripcion_util_entrada.config(text=util_resultado)

def registrar_intervencion():
    registrar_intervencion_cursor = conn_db2.cursor()

    insertar_centro = centro_desplegable.get()
    insertar_intervencion = tipo_intervencion_desplegable.get()
    insertar_subtipo_intervencion = subtipo_intervencion_desplegable.get()
    insertar_comentario = comentario_entrada.get()
    insertar_producto_final = referencia_producto_final_entrada.get()
    insertar_componente = referencia_producto_final_entrada.get()
    insertar_util = util_entrada.get()
    insertar_tiempo = tiempo_aprox_intervencion_entrada.get()

** This is the line to intert the form information.**
    registrar_intervencion_query = "INSERT INTO BIUMO220.TICKREGINTERVENCION(numerador, responsable, fecha, centro, tipo_intervencion, subtipo, comentario, ref_producto_final, df_producto_final, ref_componente, df_componente, util, df_util, tiempo_intervencion) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    registrar_intervencion_cursor.execute(registrar_intervencion_query, (numerador, uname, insertar_fecha, insertar_centro, insertar_intervencion, insertar_subtipo_intervencion, insertar_comentario, insertar_producto_final, res, insertar_componente, componente_resultado, insertar_util, util_resultado, insertar_tiempo))
    registrar_intervencion_cursor.commit()
            
numero_ticket_etiqueta = Label(text="Ticket N:", font=("Arial", 12))
numero_ticket_etiqueta.place(x=20, rely=.1, anchor="w")
global numerador
numerador = 0

responsable_etiqueta = Label(text=responsable_, font=("Arial", 12))
responsable_etiqueta.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="center")

fecha_etiqueta = Label(text=fecha_, font=("Arial", 12))
fecha_etiqueta.place(x=1100, rely=.1, anchor="e")

tipo_intervencion_etiqueta = Label(text="Tipo de Intervencion:", font=("Arial", 12))
tipo_intervencion_etiqueta.place(x=20, y=100)
tipo_intervencion_desplegable = ttk.Combobox(window, value=resultado_intervencion, font=("Arial", 12))
tipo_intervencion_desplegable.place(x=170, y=100)

tipo_intervencion_desplegable.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", seleccionar_subtipo)

subtipo_intervencion_etiqueta = Label(text="Subtipo:", font=("Arial", 12))
subtipo_intervencion_etiqueta.place(x=480, y=100)
subtipo_intervencion_desplegable = ttk.Combobox(window, value=[" "], font=("Arial", 12))
subtipo_intervencion_desplegable.place(x=550, y=100)

centro_etiqueta = Label(text="Centro:", font=("Arial", 12))
centro_etiqueta.place(x=850, y=100)
centro_desplegable = ttk.Combobox(window, value=resultado_centro, font=("Arial", 12))
centro_desplegable.place(x=910, y=100)

comentario_etiqueta = Label(text="Comentario:", font=("Arial", 12))
comentario_etiqueta.place(x=20, y=150)
comentario_entrada = Entry(textvariable=comentario, width="110", font=("Arial", 12))
comentario_entrada.place(x=120, y=150)

referencia_producto_final_etiqueta = Label(text="Ref. Producto Final:", font=("Arial", 12))
referencia_producto_final_etiqueta.place(x=20, y=200)
referencia_producto_final_entrada = Entry(textvariable=ref_producto_final, width="15", font=("Arial", 12))
referencia_producto_final_entrada.place(x=170, y=200)

referencia_producto_final_entrada.bind('<Return>', producto_final_descripcion_familia)

descripcion_producto_final_entrada1 = Label(font=("Arial", 12))
descripcion_producto_final_entrada1.place(x=320, y=200)

descripcion_producto_final_entrada2 = Label(font=("Arial", 12))
descripcion_producto_final_entrada2.place(x=520, y=200)

referencia_componente_etiqueta = Label(text="Ref. Componente:", font=("Arial", 12))
referencia_componente_etiqueta.place(x=20, y=250)
referencia_componente_entrada = Entry(textvariable=ref_componente, width="15", font=("Arial", 12))
referencia_componente_entrada.place(x=160, y=250)

referencia_componente_entrada.bind('<Return>', componente_descripcion_familia)

descripcion_componente_entrada = Label(font=("Arial", 12))
descripcion_componente_entrada.place(x=300, y=250)

util_etiqueta = Label(text="Util:", font=("Arial", 12))
util_etiqueta.place(x=20, y=300)
util_entrada = Entry(textvariable=util, width="15", font=("Arial", 12))
util_entrada.place(x=60, y=300)

util_entrada.bind('<Return>', util_descripcion_familia)

descripcion_util_entrada = Label(font=("Arial", 12))
descripcion_util_entrada.place(x=200, y=300)

tiempo_aprox_intervencion_etiqueta = Label(text="Tiempo Aprox. Intervencion:", font=("Arial", 12))
tiempo_aprox_intervencion_etiqueta.place(x=20, y=350)
tiempo_aprox_intervencion_entrada = Entry(textvariable=tiempo_aprox_intervencion, width="15", font=("Arial", 12))
tiempo_aprox_intervencion_entrada.place(x=220, y=350)

registrar_intervencion_boton = Button(window, text="REGISTRAR", font=("Arial", 12), command=registrar_intervencion)
registrar_intervencion_boton.place(x=20, y=400)


window.mainloop()
```

And this is my table information:

```
CREATE TABLE BIUMO220/TICKREGINTERVENCION(                          
     numerador int not null,
     responsable char(50) not null,              
     fecha date not null,
     centro char(50) not null,                      
     tipo_intervencion char(50) not null,
     subtipo char(50) not null,     
     comentario char(500),
     ref_producto_final char(50),                  
     df_producto_final char(500),
     ref_componente char(50),               
     df_componente char(500),
     util char(50),
     df_util char(500),          
     tiempo_intervencion char(5) not null)
```

I created that table with very huge table fields becasue I thought that the error was because one field was not enough big for the information, but I was wrong.

This is the Python error that i get when trying to insert the information of the form:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py_install\py_394\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<string>", line 157, in registrar_intervencion
pyodbc.Error: ('00000', '[00000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Controller]SQL dat argument out of range. (30030) (SQLBindParameter)')
```

Comment: What values were you inserting? Could you minimize the code so that it only includes neccessary lines?

Comment: I do not know if I can, everything is necesary for the form. For example, all the comboboxes information is dynamic, so I need a query for each of them. But I'm trying to insert all the ".get()" variables that you see above the insert statement. And I few static variables such as "numerador, uname and insertar_fecha".

Comment: @1511 Just print the values of the variables (in a debug line) before the INSERT statement runs.  There may be a an expectation that a CHAR is no longer than 254 bytes.

Comment: I just tried that, and everything seems fine, the largest field is 97 characters, should I edit the table and put char(200) just in case?

Comment: Did not work, I tried to put large camps to literally everything, just in case some random white spaces are being introduced, but I get the exact same error... jesus...

Comment: What's the date format in your DSN ?

Comment: yyyy-mm-dd, yeah i saw that a lil bit later when I posted the question, now it's changed to the right format, the error persists.

Comment: if you `pip install ebcdic` then `import ebcdic` then `<each var>.encode("cpxxx")` does one fail ? (where xxx id the CCSID of the column)

Comment: Same error, did that with every string field.

Comment: @1511 enable odbc tracing to see what is happening under the covers. Refer to the i access documentation for details of tracing.   Ensure your versions (of all components used in the stack) are at currently supported levels.

Comment: This is the log part that gets the error for sure, not sure what that means, gonna try to figure it out.

Comment: python          3ca0-4a30 EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
  SQLSMALLINT                  3 <SQL_HANDLE_STMT>
  SQLHANDLE           0x000001E83D35DA70
  SQLSMALLINT                  1 
  SQLWCHAR *          0x000000B02E9E9C80 [       5] "00000"
  SQLINTEGER *        0x000000B02E9E9C58 (30030)
  SQLWCHAR *          0x000001E83CB63C70 [      88] "[IBM][Controlador ODBC de System i Access]Argumento de tipo de datos SQL fuera de rango."
  SQLSMALLINT               1023 
  SQLSMALLINT *       0x000000B02E9E9C50 (88)

Comment: you pass array objects as arguments to the .execute() method when inserting. (example `res` and `componente_resultado` and `util_resultado` . This may cause the symptom.

Comment: That is completly right, I just made a quick test and that was the problem. But the thing is, I wanna store those strings that are inside the array. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect coding was the immediate cause of this symptom:

> pyodbc.Error: ('00000', '[00000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC
> Controller]SQL dat argument out of range. (30030) (SQLBindParameter)')

You are passing arrays as parameters to the `.execute()` method, but the interface may expect scalars instead. For example in your code fragment these objects are arrays `res` and `componente_resultado` and `util_resultado`.

It is wise to normalize your data model to store a single scalar value in a specific column. It's unwise to store a list of values in a single column. Any good text book on data modelling will explain the rationale for this, and the consequences of denormalizing to break these rules.

If you choose to denormalize and store a list of values in a single column then you can `.join()` the array entries to make a scalar (with some delimiter) before supplying the result as a parameter to `.execute()` as long as you understand this is bad practice and will have consequences and you already ensured the target column is big enough.